# Flutter @Freezed() vs @freezed annotation

Tags: flutter, dart, annotations, freezed, flutter-freezed

What are the differences between `@Freezed()` and `@freezed` annotations ?

In official [freezed documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed#the-syntax) the `@freezed` annotation used.
But there are some tutorials like this [Medium post](https://tomicriedel.medium.com/flutter-freezed-the-complete-crashcourse-c942e9aa2428) where `@Freezed()` annotation used instead.

I tried both and in my case didn't find any difference

```dart
@freezed
class Post with _$Post {
  const factory Post({
    required int id,
    required String title,
    required String text,
    required String imageUrl,
  }) = _Post;

  factory Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$PostFromJson(json);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize key and value with something different using `@Freezed` and `@FreezedUnionValue` decorators.

Whereas with the lowercase `@freezed` you cannot customise.

So essentially the `@Freezed(...)` allows you to customise the value and key.

[Link to documentation with relevant section highlighted](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed#fromjsontojson).